# Is it good practice to not use locks for read only resources in multiprocessing.manager in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following Model.py resource that loads a very large model and I serve it using `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`:

```
import time 
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        #load model, takes around 15 min
        time.sleep(3) #Simulate loading the file
        self.model = [1,2,3]
    
    def query(self, i):
        #Do computation heavy work using loaded model, around 5 seconds/query
        time.sleep(3)
        return self.model[i]


model = Model()
def get_model():
    return model 

manager = BaseManager(('', 37844), b'password')
manager.register('get_model', get_model)
server = manager.get_server()
server.serve_forever()
```

Now I have multiple processes/threads that consume this model:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Process
import time 

def do_computation(i):
    manager = BaseManager(('', 37844), b'password')
    manager.register('get_model')
    manager.connect()
    return manager.get_model().query(i)

def do_computation_parallel():
    manager = BaseManager(('', 37844), b'password')
    manager.register('get_model')
    manager.connect()

    p1 = Process(target=do_computation, args=(0,))
    p2 = Process(target=do_computation, args=(1,))

    t1 = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(time.time()-t1)

do_computation_parallel()
```

Now the code above returns around 3 seconds which is what I expect. The first process takes around 15 minutes to initialize (in `Model.__init__`), and each process takes around 3 seconds to query the model object after that.

My question is, is what I am doing safe/best practice? The model is immutable so none of the processes or threads will try to change it, just consume it.

Comment: Conflicts happen when you have a write operation. If you are sure you only read, there would be no need for locks

Comment: Should not need locks if immutable, also  cache the computation based on the query, so you only spend the 5 seconds the first time you use the query.